# mysqli SELECT until a certail amount sum

Tags: mysql

I have a table name foods, there have various foods with different calories. For example bellow:

Table: foods

```
id    name      calories
-----------------------
1     beef      200
2     tomato    400
3     carrot    500
4     nuts      800
```

what I want: I want to stop selecting food in my query when the calory amount goes to a certain amount I ascertain. like bellow:

```
SELECT * FROM foods WHERE SUM(calories)=1000
```

Comment: Can u plz paste ur output.

Comment: No output come. even no error

Comment: i think you need a function for that. select will get all the rows and gets a comparison with something given. what you want is to keep adding row by row till you reach your threshold. sum(calories) would give you an error, select sum(calories) would give you the sum of all records

Comment: I tried with sum(calories) for making comparison. BUt it does not work. I need any query function that will work what I want like. I will appreciate if you can suggest me a mysql query statement

Comment: $sql2="SELECT * FROM foods WHERE SUM(calories)=1000";
    $result2=mysqli_query($db, $sql2);
     
     while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
      $name=$row["food_name"];
      $calory=$row["calories"];

      echo "Name:". $name;
     }

Comment: Hi, I'm not understanding what exactly you want to do here, you want to select all values where Sum calories is 1000 but I don't understand how that output should look like, probably you will have more than one combination, do you want to select only one? Can you explain it a little beter... tnx